# How to get the bigger value of two within every n-minute time frame in TimescaleDB

Tags: sql, time, case, bucket, timescaledb

I want to compare the sum of two attributes A and B between timestamps x and y for every 15 minutes so I get the bigger value within this 15 minute time frame.

Table

`id      A      B       timestamp
 1       5     10       2016-05-16 18:00:01
 2       5     10       2016-05-16 18:15:00
 3      15      5       2016-05-16 18:15:01
 4      15      5       2016-05-16 18:30:00`

So the query (x = 2016-05-16 18:00:01 and y = 2016-05-16 18:30:00) used with this table should return:

`value      timestamp
 20         2016-05-16 18:00:01
 30         2016-05-16 18:15:01`

I think that you need some kind of combination of a CASE and a time_bucket() expression.

Comment: Hi @all, thanks beforehand for helping out :)

Comment: which SQL enginer are using?

Comment: @zealous It is sum(A) or sum(B) depending which is bigger in the current time frame.

Comment: @zealous I am using a TimescaleDB instance.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the function `greatest`. It returns the larger of two values, and you can pass the aggregates of the two columns

```
SELECT 
  greatest(sum(a), sum(b)) as value, 
  time_bucket('15m', t, '1s'::interval) as t
FROM k
WHERE t >= '2016-05-16 18:00:01' AND t <= '2016-05-16 18:30:00'
GROUP BY 2;
```

Notice that third argument in the `time_bucket` function. Time bucket by default rounds to the start of the 15m bucket, you use the third argument to specify an offset. From your example I saw that you want buckets to start at 1s offset.

Comment: It might be possible to simplify this more, but you get the gist